# Sendmail connection closing using XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, sendmail

I tried every solution out there, tried windows XP compatibility, always run as admin, tried both SSL and TLS, but each time I try to send email from localhost drupal installation, I get connection closed gracefully.

This is the debug error I get:

```
16/02/20 10:58:21 ** Connecting to smtp.gmail.com:587
16/02/20 10:58:21 ** Connected.
16/02/20 10:58:21 << 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP v22sm11360010wmv.12 - gsmtp<EOL>
16/02/20 10:58:21 >> EHLO Jura-PC<EOL>
16/02/20 10:58:21 << 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [212.111.4.206]<EOL>250-SIZE 35882577<EOL>250-8BITMIME<EOL>250-STARTTLS<EOL>250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES<EOL>250-PIPELINING<EOL>250-CHUNKING<EOL>250 SMTPUTF8<EOL>
16/02/20 10:58:21 ** Authenticating as jura.kubicku@gmail.com
16/02/20 10:58:21 >> STARTTLS<EOL>
16/02/20 10:58:21 << 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<EOL>
16/02/20 10:58:21 >> QUIT<EOL>
16/02/20 10:58:21 <<  5  1VČ8ô{Őă?:©_ű¨NňťsYŁI    őo™®öcě  /      ˙   #        „0‚€0‚h Bă ýN†úX0
   *†H†÷
 0I10  UUS10U

Google Inc1%0#UGoogle Internet Authority G20
160211105727Z
160511000000Z0h10  UUS10U
California10U
Mountain View10U

Google Inc10Usmtp.gmail.com0‚"0
   *†H†÷
 ‚ 0‚
‚ Ď92¬rŰ„ÓvŘ2˘b‰š±qay¸Ş’í=j<˘|'Q’ôŹ.Ł“ŔýŽ^ŢÖZďzWµ´OK¦>—(ą¶–‹Ę,lWĎSŮx±SŚĐXą$¶ë–Wyíś†7Ťi$8mŚ-ĐfJŔJŻŘ·,źĺýóĂŢĚz›† î
    ¤5ÜËŕeß“ęţo†D°üí(Łçá_Aěi^bŻ©!ĄŠ9a>Í^Ő
0ĺ HnxÓÁěŞŤe a(C!"şŃŽöJţÖËű
ŁaTPI; QĘăâ«—¤ww'k˙KO}˛řč„(Š2O‘•“BJSşĹ0‹ŐzĚP‚Y+eć,@Ł Ł‚K0‚G0U%0++0U0‚smtp.gmail.com0h+\0Z0++0†http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crt0++0†http://clients1.google.com/ocsp0UeÂß·h¨~ëµOs,XżřŤĺŇ0U˙0 0U#0€JÝĽöhµvő¶»bşZ/0!U 00
+Öy0g00U)0'0% # !†http://pki.google.com/GIAG2.crl0
   *†H†÷
 ‚ ÁÂ6‰—x_ś‡€ó~š%Ő ˝iý‡{Áý őçGŁąĆĘ¸şSžéV{Ů©ë7bĆ:˘Đz“âH$]€  ,‘&îë  @†wĄj ¨Ö¶»EĄhç2US=kÓYÜtźXćĎ•ÜŽh2A„éťÄ”Óá©—+żvxDźj”°»éł@B×ńaJŃééúł˛Ęý=µ)÷9$}Dcăi÷îţÝăA
s}Ą†Ń°ŕ´ń‚GÇ~6Ř–ŠvkÉR`
qË)i|]‡.|ča¶7’­•üŐÁ QOR+Ô)­Ď¤Ám\‘{É:ž†Vę‹+:®ą ô0‚đ0‚Ř :0
   *†H†÷
 0B10  UUS10U

GeoTrust Inc.10UGeoTrust Global CA0
130405151556Z
161231235959Z0I10  UUS10U

Google Inc1%0#UGoogle Internet Au
16/02/20 10:58:21 << thority G20‚"0<CR>   *†H†÷<CR> ‚ 0‚
‚ ś*w\ŘP‘:Ł‚ŕŘPHĽ‰?ńpF~ŕŹĹń‰Î!îZţa
·2D‰ tSOU¤Î‚b•îëY_Ćá€Ä^”?Ľ[H8ôS÷$ćű‘éÄĎôS
ôJüźTŢ}ľ ko‡ŔĐP(0@ÚsQl˙:<§7Ž˝Kë}$Ţćůü1qű”Ő`ó.JŻBŇËęÄj˛ĚSÝK‹ČaÍť¨>c+„5ie„ČĹF"řS•ľă€JĆ*ěş— Ç9™ đaz•%ŚNRuâ¶íĘüÎ"jłNĎF——~Ŕ±Ţ{ŻE3Ďş>q·Ţô%%Â
5‰ťťűy‰7ĹŻŽri Łç0ä0U#0€ŔzhŤ‰ű«d}Ş}e¸ĘĚN0UJÝĽöhµvő¶»bşZ/0U˙0.+"0 0+0†http://g.symcd.com0U˙0˙ 05U.0,0* ( &†$http://g.symcb.com/crls/gtglobal.crl0U 00
+Öy0
   *†H†÷
 ‚ Şú© Íjgí^Ô~ŢÄŕ% Ĺ$ű©Č-m~Ţť‚e,c4f>éRÂ´Ë/÷_™:jśPz…Ś}Ń*H„Ó    l|ÂÍ5źó‚îRŢh_ä Š –÷)ŤšMË¨Ţ†Č
oV‡}?Üúy}!ůČ:/QvŚÇA’qŹ%Î7řJL #ďÄ5®ŕ#€s|M4.ČnÖ™„spňíUîęgî2ë,Ýg?ö‹ÂpŢ[ ć»Ó6"ll°5Bl   =“éd    "…źÂs!Óć_€äŤ…":s±`Ž®hâô>—ç` h6Ţ:ÖâC•[7’»Ť×­RdW–Ů^4~Č5Ř 0‚}0‚ć »ć0
   *†H†÷
 0N10  UUS10U
Equifax1-0+U$Equifax Secure Certificate Authority0
020521040000Z
180821040000Z0B10  UUS10U

GeoTrust Inc.10UGeoTrust Global CA0‚"0
   *†H†÷
 ‚ 0‚
‚ ÚĚc0ýô#V~[ß<l8äq·x‘ÔĽˇŘLř¨C¶éM!ÚX/f9)˝x‹ť8č·j~q¤ćÄ`¦°ď€ä‰(ž%Öíó­¦‘ÇÉB5ť­F’.OĘń‡CÁ•W-Pď‰-€zW­ňî_kŇ Ťąř5ŮŔFŁ{rČ‘żÉU+ÍĐ—>ś&dĚßÎqĘNćÔŐ{©ÍUŢČěŇ^8Sĺ\OŚ-ţP#6üfćËŽ¤9 ·•9‘ţ8.ŃšöM>oŻ,Ź`9âú6S9Ô^&+Ű=¨˝2ë(Rqĺ«3=á8»6„bśyę0ô_Ŕ+čqkäů Łđ0í0U#0€Hćhů+Ň˛•×GŘ# O3źÔ0UŔzhŤ‰ű«d}Ş}e¸ĘĚN0U˙0˙0U˙0:
16/02/20 10:58:21 << U3010/ - +†)http://crl.geotrust.com/crls/secureca.crl0NU G0E0CU  0;09+-https://www.geotrust.com/resources/repository0
   *†H†÷
  vánNK†0˛ĎđÇÇq~fîÂíÔ;˙đđČNÖC8°ą0}ĐU˘jË6śčHfŁm¸ÔGţ‹Z\sü®Ů28«—4Ş–ŇëŁI¶»ĺ‘ď6ëVoĘÚĽscä{>"Ë=í_8tśăPNˇŻîaň„?    
16/02/20 10:58:21 ** Disconnected.
16/02/20 10:58:21 ** Disconnecting from smtp.gmail.com:587
16/02/20 10:58:21 ** Disconnected.
16/02/20 10:58:21 ** Disconnected.
16/02/20 10:58:21 ** Connection Closed Gracefully.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually managed to find a root of the problem: my current drupal package does not send encrypted emails, so when I tried to connect to TLS and SSL on Gmail, I got rejected, because the email was not encrypted.

So I had to resort using other mail service, that allows unsecured port 25 connection, hope this helps someone in the future!